# Forecasting with panel data/ time series

Tags: forecasting, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have three questions for you regarding the prediction of panel data.

There is a function `predict.plm()` in the `plm` package for `R`. As far as I have seen, this can only be used for Fixed Effects Models. The reason for this is that only the effects in the case of these models can be estimated. The effects for Random Effect Models do not matter here.

Also, I could not figure out how the time effects are estimated/predicted. Thus, the individual-specific effects can simply be integrated into the model, since they do not change over time. But how to predict the time effects within the `predict()` function?

And how are adjustments to the model predicted? For example, if I have lags in my original model.

I think basically it makes more sense for me to do the prediction manually, since I also want to do out-of-sample predictions and from my understanding this doesn't work so easily with the `predict()` function. Do any of you have any idea how this is done? So at least in the case of normal time series, then I could derive that.

Going further, I would be interested in how to manually adjust the point prediction to an interval prediction.

I am lost. So if one of you has at least an approach, that would help me a lot!

Edit: I have a data set over one year with 12 observation points for all of the 10 individuals. I have a lot of variables that I have already selected for the one model. After various tests, I have found that I should compute a fixed effects model for this data and also have 2nd order lags in two of the five variables that I have included in the model. Now I want to make a prediction for the next two months and validate the model using a rolling cross-validation.
I also have other dependent variables that I want to model within different models. These can of course be RE models in these cases, which then have to be dealt with differently in the forecast.

Comment: What are your data and the model? There are no time effects or lags unless you made them part of the model and then they are used as you defined it in the model.

Comment: I will have to make different models. Currently I am working with a Fixed Effects model with two-ways effects. I also have lags in two of my coefficients.
However, since I have other data available, which will certainly require a random effects model at some point, I am also thinking about this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the data and the models in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

`predict()` as in `plm` 2.6-2 will work with random effect models as well.

The fixed effects case is somewhat special, though: Regarding out-of-sample prediction with fixed effects models, it is not clear how data relating to fixed effects not in the original model are to be treated, e.g., data for an individual not contained in the orignal data set the model was estimated on. (This is rather a methodological question than a programming question).

The version 2.6-2 of `plm` allows `predict` for fixed effect models with the original data and with out-of-sample data (see `?predict.plm`).

Find below an example with 10 firms for model estimation and the data to be used for prediction contains a firm not contained in the original data set (besides that firm, there are also years not contained in the original model object but these are irrelevant here as it is a one-way individual model). It is unclear what the fixed effect of that out-of-sample firm would be. Hence, by default, no predicted value is given (`NA` value). If argument `na.fill` is set to `TRUE`, the (weighted) mean of the fixed effects contained in the original model object is used as a best guess.

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

# fit a fixed effect model
fit.fe <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within")

# generate 55 new observations of three firms used for prediction:
#  * firm 1 with years 1935:1964 (has out-of-sample years 1955:1964), 
#  * firm 2 with years 1935:1949 (all in sample),
#  * firm 11 with years 1935:1944 (firm 11 is out-of-sample)
set.seed(42L)

new.value2   <- runif(55, min = min(Grunfeld$value),   max = max(Grunfeld$value))
new.capital2 <- runif(55, min = min(Grunfeld$capital), max = max(Grunfeld$capital))

newdata <- data.frame(firm = c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 15), rep(11, 10)),
                      year = c(1935:(1935+29), 1935:(1935+14), 1935:(1935+9)),
                      value = new.value2, capital = new.capital2)
# make pdata.frame
newdata.p <- pdata.frame(newdata, index = c("firm", "year"))

## predict from fixed effect model with new data as pdata.frame
predict(fit.fe, newdata = newdata.p) # has NA values for the 11'th firm

## set na.fill = TRUE to have the weighted mean used to for fixed effects -> no NA values
predict(fit.fe, newdata = newdata.p, na.fill = TRUE)
```

NB: When you input a plain data.frame as `newdata`, it is not clear how the data related to the individuals and time periods, which is why the weighted mean of fixed effects from the original model object is used for all observations in `newdata` and a warning is printed. For fixed effect model prediction, it is reasonable to assume the user can provide information (via a pdata.frame) how the data the user wants to use for prediction relates to the individual and time dimension of panel data.